# Access a nested class if the container doesn't have its instance

Tags: c++, class, oop, subclass

I have a generated .h file and I want to access one of the getters from main.cpp. The header may seem complicated:

```
#include <kaitai/kaitaistruct.h>
#include <kaitai/kaitaistream.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

class protocol_t : public kaitai::kstruct 
{
private:
    std::vector<packet_t*>* m_packet;
    protocol_t* m__root;
    kaitai::kstruct* m__parent;

public:
    class packet_t;
    protocol_t(kaitai::kstream* p_io, kaitai::kstruct* p_parent = 0, protocol_t* p_root = 0);
    ~protocol_t();
    std::vector<packet_t*>* packet() const { return m_packet; }
    protocol_t* _root() const { return m__root; }
    kaitai::kstruct* _parent() const { return m__parent; }
};

class packet_t : public kaitai::kstruct 
{
private:
    uint8_t m_pkt_id;
    kaitai::kstruct* m_body;
    protocol_t* m__root;
    protocol_t* m__parent;

public:
    uint8_t pkt_id() const { return m_pkt_id; }
    kaitai::kstruct* body() const { return m_body; }
    protocol_t* _root() const { return m__root; }
    protocol_t* _parent() const { return m__parent; }

    class handshake_t;
    class datagram_t;

    packet_t(kaitai::kstream* p_io, protocol_t* p_parent = 0, protocol_t* p_root = 0);
    ~packet_t();
};

class handshake_t : public kaitai::kstruct 
{

public:
    std::string version() const { return m_version; }
    protocol_t* _root() const { return m__root; }
    protocol_t::packet_t* _parent() const { return m__parent; }

    handshake_t(kaitai::kstream* p_io, protocol_t::packet_t* p_parent = 0, protocol_t* p_root = 0);
    ~handshake_t();

private:
    std::string m_version;
    protocol_t* m__root;
    protocol_t::packet_t* m__parent;
};

class datagram_t : public kaitai::kstruct {

public:
    uint16_t left_time() const { return m_left_time; }
    int8_t temperature() const { return m_temperature; }
    protocol_t* _root() const { return m__root; }
    protocol_t::packet_t* _parent() const { return m__parent; }

    datagram_t(kaitai::kstream* p_io, protocol_t::packet_t* p_parent = 0, protocol_t* p_root = 0);
    ~datagram_t();

private:
    uint16_t m_left_time;
    int8_t m_temperature;
    protocol_t* m__root;
    protocol_t::packet_t* m__parent;
};
```

In main.cpp I create an object of protocol_t d and of course my attempt to access its temperature

```
cout << (*(*d.packet())[0]->body())->temperature() << endl;
```

fails. There is simply no instance of datagram_t in packet_t, so I cannot reach it. Though I guess it can be done somehow.

Comment: ***cout << (*(*d.packet())[0]->body())->temperature() << endl;*** Please don't write production code like this!

Comment: Why does m_packet need to be a pointer to a vector?

Comment: Sure. I'm just trying to quick-and-dirty get the field.

Comment: Well, `cout << (*d.packet())[0]->pkt_id()<< endl;` gives me the needed value. And `cout << (*d.packet())[0]->body() << endl;` outputs an address in memory. But when I try to access this address, nothing happens.

Comment: I can't change the generated code. I'd sure make it more humane if I wrote it, but I need to use it as is:(

Answer (score 2):

Let's evaluate this expression using a paper and a pen:

```
(*(*d.packet())[0]
```

`d.packet()` returns a `std::vector<packet_t*> *`:

```
std::vector<packet_t*>* packet() const { return m_packet; }
```

That's what it's declared to return. Onto the next step:

`*d.packet()`, therefore, gives you a `std::vector<packet_t*>`, the result of applying the `*` operator to the pointer returned from the class method (actually, the result is a reference, but that's not germane to the issue at hand).

Next step:

`(*(*d.packet())` - and that's a problem right here. `std::vector<packet_t *>` is, obviously, not a pointer to which a `*` operator can be applied. It is, obviously, a vector.

That's the reason for your compilation error.

Comment: But `(*d.packet())[0]->body()->temperature()` doesn't work as well. Please, note that body() returns a pointer too. I thought I was unpointering the body by the second `(*(*d.packet())[0]...)`, not the vector.

Comment: I still don't get it

Comment: "Doesn't work as well" is not a useful problem description. First of all, your compiler's actual error message will tell you what the problem is. Although C++ compiler error messages have a reputation for being confusing, it's not the case here. By following this paper and pencil approach you should be able to easily figure out the answer yourself. Free clue: what does `body()` return? No, not what you ***want*** it to return, but what it actually does. Does it have a `temperature()` method? Remember: a computer will only do what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do.

Comment: Yes, it gives an error: 'class kaitai::kstruct' has no member named `'temperature'
     cout << ((*d.packet())[0]->body())->temperature() << endl;`

Comment: Ok, that's the compiler's error message, and, as I suspected, it is very clear and tells you exactly what the problem is. I also asked a few other things: what does your `body()` return, and whether it's a pointer to a structure that has a `temperature()` method. Obviously not, and that's your problem. And that's exactly what your compiler is telling you.